# Returning values of keys with values greater than 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get this code to return all the values of the keys with values greater than 6. Not sure how to go about it keep getting errors.

```
   <div>
      <% {'b' => '5', 'c'=> '6', 'd' => '7', 'e' => '8'}.each do |letter, value| %>
      <% if key > 6 The more valuable keys have values of <%= value %> %>
   </div>
```

Comment: Try to wright proper subject. You should write **couldn't print values of keys with values greater than 6**, instead **Returning values of keys with values greater than 6**. I don't know about you, it matters for us.. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot refer to the variable `letter` using an entirely different variable `key`. I have no idea why you thought you can.